# Polygon annotation in PDFBox PDAnnotation

Tags: java, annotations, pdfbox

I want to add the polygon in the PDF at the given coordinates, I referred this [link](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/Annotation.java.html) for adding the annotation of circle and rectangle, but it does not contain anything for polygon. Does anyone know how to do it? Or does anyone know where do I get all documentation about PDFBox annotation.

Here I am sharing what I'vs done until now. But I couldn't proceed further.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle; 
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColor;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDActionGoTo;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDActionURI;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotation;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationLine;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationText; 
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationLink;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationMarkup;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationSquareCircle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationTextMarkup;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDBorderStyleDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.destination.PDPageDestination;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.destination.PDPageFitWidthDestination;

 public class Polygon{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Loading the PDF File
    File file = new File("abc.pdf");
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
    System.out.println("PDF Loaded.");

    PDPage page = document.getPage(0);
    List<PDAnnotation> polygon = page.getAnnotations();
    // Color of polygon
    PDColor color = new PDColor(new float[] {0, 0, 1}, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
    // Define border thickness
    PDBorderStyleDictionary thickness = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
    thickness.setWidth((float)2);

    float[] vertices = {418, 110, 523, 110, 522, 132, 419, 133};

    PDAnnotationSquareCircle lines = new PDAnnotationSquareCircle(PDAnnotationSquareCircle.SUB_TYPE_POLYGON);
    lines.setColor(color);
    lines.setBorderStyle(thickness);

    /*****************
     * 
     *  ????
     *  *************************************/

    // Save annotations
    document.save(file);

    // Close document
    document.close();
}
}
```

As far I have seen, There isn't any method for adding vertices in polygon in PDAnnotation jar. So is there any way we can draw polygon here?

Thanks.

Comment: The example is outdated (many years old), the current example (for 2.0) is in `AddAnnotation.java` in the source code download. It does not have an example for `PDAnnotationPolygon`. Besides rectangle and color, you just need to call `setVertices()` with your coordinates. The documentation is in the PDF specification. However the current implementation has a flaw: they don't add the appearance stream, so display will not work in all viewers. Display does work in Adobe Reader. If you need the appearance stream, use the development trunk.

Comment: Thanks for reply @TilmanHausherr, can you please provide a link for documentation of the polygon if you have?

Comment: The javadoc and the sample code is the documentation. The methods mostly mirror the PDF specification, see https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf . But I don't see what the problem is for you. How to set rectangle and color can be seen in the example mentioned. Setting the vertices is also trivial, assuming you know what x and y coordinate series you want to set. I suggest you edit your question with the code that you tried.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr You probably should make this an actual answer... ;)

Comment: @mkl Not yet, I'd like to know what the real issue here is. Maybe the OP scared for having an empty screen. Or maybe the OP really wants an example. Maybe the OP is a java beginner and doesn't know how to show a javadoc.

Comment: Okay, the problem here is, I am using the `PDAnnotation` jar and I think the method that you're suggesting `setVertices()` is in `FDFAnnotation` jar, so I am getting blocked here.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I've added code I've done. Can you please have a look at it and just tell me what can be done? Thanks.

Comment: OK I see the problem. Sorry. PDAnnotationPolygon doesn't exist in 2.0, I was looking at the trunk (3.0) the whole time where everything is nicer. PDAnnotationMarkup needs to be used and the rest is low level :-( I'll create an answer later today.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Okay Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that will soon be added to the AddAnnotations.java example from the source code download:

```
static final float INCH = 72;
float pw = page1.getMediaBox().getUpperRightX();
float ph = page1.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY();

PDAnnotationMarkup polygon = new PDAnnotationMarkup();
polygon.getCOSObject().setName(COSName.SUBTYPE, PDAnnotationMarkup.SUB_TYPE_POLYGON);
position = new PDRectangle();
position.setLowerLeftX(pw - INCH);
position.setLowerLeftY(ph - INCH);
position.setUpperRightX(pw - 2 * INCH);
position.setUpperRightY(ph - 2 * INCH);
polygon.setRectangle(position);
polygon.setColor(blue); // border color
polygon.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.IC, red.toCOSArray()); // interior color
COSArray triangleVertices = new COSArray();
triangleVertices.add(new COSFloat(pw - INCH));
triangleVertices.add(new COSFloat(ph - 2 * INCH));
triangleVertices.add(new COSFloat(pw - INCH * 1.5f));
triangleVertices.add(new COSFloat(ph - INCH));
triangleVertices.add(new COSFloat(pw - 2 * INCH));
triangleVertices.add(new COSFloat(ph - 2 * INCH));
polygon.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.VERTICES, triangleVertices);
polygon.setBorderStyle(borderThick);

annotations.add(polygon);
```

to adjust your own code, you need to adjust the rectangle and pass your vertices:

```
position.setLowerLeftX(418);
position.setLowerLeftY(110);
position.setUpperRightX(523);
position.setUpperRightY(133);
polygon.setRectangle(position);
float[] vertices = {418, 110, 523, 110, 522, 132, 419, 133};
COSArray verticesArray = new COSArray();
for (float v : vertices)
    verticesArray.add(new COSFloat(v));
polygon.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.VERTICES, verticesArray);
```

This is for 2.0 only. In 3.0 there will be a PDAnnotationPolygon type with appropriate methods. That version will also support the construction of appearance streams, i.e. you will be able to show the PDF with other viewers than Adobe Reader. Most viewers, e.g. PDF.js and PDFBox don't build missing appearances so you'll see nothing.

If you need the appearance for 2.0 you can try with the code in the file ShowAnnotation-6.java in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3353 .

To test with the 3.0 version, get the jar here:
https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/

To build the appearance, call `polygon.constructAppearances();`

Comment: one more thing, I want to add sticky note in the pdf, I have used the `PDAnnotationText`, it's showing me the sticky note but the icon is not as we have seen in the Acrobat Reader, is there any way I can get the similar icon as the Acrobat Reader? Thanks in advance.

Comment: call `setName()`. The standard names are Comment, Key, Note, Help, NewParagraph, Paragraph, Insert. Some more that Adobe supports are: Circle, Cross, Star, Check, RightArrow, RightPointer, UpArrow. If you tell me how it should look I may be able to tell you the name.

Comment: I want the first icon in the Annotation tab for the sticky note : http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/chapter09_0321751256/elementLinks/rc_01.jpg

Comment: The speech bubble is the "Comment". The default is "Note" which looks like paper.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!!! And one last thing, is there anything in PDFBox for free-form drawing?

Comment: Yes, the ink annotation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174313/discussion-between-suhas-bhattu-and-tilman-hausherr).